# Convert an Array like string to array in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string (something like var_dump) and need to convert it to an array.
I can use **explode** and **str_replace** ...
but i need to know is there any other or better solution for this issue or not. string is line by line ...

example string:

```
$myString = "something => somevalue
anotherthing => somevalue
A => B
X => Z";
```

need to convert to:

```
$myArray = array(something => somevalue,anotherthing => somevalue,A => B,X => Z");
```

Comment: explode it by newline, then explode each line by arrow. [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: It would be better if you used a format that's designed to be parsed, like JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few exotic options.

INI parser:

```
$array = parse_ini_string(str_replace('=>', '=', $string));
```

URL parser:

```
parse_str(str_replace(' => ', '=', str_replace(PHP_EOL, '&', $string)), $array);
```

RegExp:

```
preg_match_all('/(.*) \=\> (.*)/', $string, $matches);

$array = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a nested [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$myString = "something => somevalue
anotherthing => somevalue
A => B
X => Z";

$myArray = array();
foreach (explode(PHP_EOL, $myString) as $line) {
    list($key, $value) = explode(' => ', $line);
    $myArray[$key] = $value;
}
print_r($myArray);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [something] => somevalue
    [anotherthing] => somevalue
    [A] => B
    [X] => Z
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/XKYK7)